# Enlazar varias tablas a otra para obtener grupos de registros

Tags: android, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli, sqlite

Hace ya unas semanas creé una base de datos para utilizarla en mi app de Android. Resulta que estas dos semana he estado dándole vueltas a un problema que tenia, y por muchas soluciones que sacara, me daban errores y ya no se que hacer.

Os explico:

Mi base de datos es para registrar qué esta cursando cada alumno, por lo que dicho alumno tendrá que registrar el `centro` donde se realiza el estudio (ej: Colegio Mayor) , el `estudio` (ejemplo: ESO), los `periodos` de ese estudio (los trimestres), las `asignaturas` y lo `deberes`. También existen `eventos`, como por ejemplo, excursiones.

El problema es que las `asignaturas`, los `deberes` y los `eventos` tienen grupos de horas y esas horas están todas en la tabla `horario`, porque no pueden repetirse (una persona no puede estar en dos sitios distintos a la vez). Un ejemplo claro:

> El `evento` 1 tiene los `horarios` 1, 2, 3, 4 y 5.
>
> La `asignatura` 4 tiene los `horarios` 8, 12, 13, 24 y 26.
>
> El `deber` 3 tiene los `horarios` 6 y 9.

Teniendo esto, decidí que la mejor forma de solucionarlo era introduciendo el `id` de las tablas en la tabla `horario`, así podía enlazar fácilmente con el registro de la tabla al cual pertenece ese `horario`, pero no lo puedo aplicar porque si no, en la tabla `horario` tendría la clave primaria `idHorario` más las claves ajenas de las tablas `Asignaturas`, `Eventos` y `Deberes`, y realmente no se si esta forma es muy optima.

Al no se muy optima la primera opción, pensé en otra forma y decidí que la tabla horarios tuviera un nuevo campo llamado `Grupo` que fuera como un id (no es un id) que enlazara con las demás tablas, pero tengo problemas porque no me deja enlazarlo ya que necesita ser indexado y al no ser una clave (es solo un campo) no puedo crear la relación. Pongo un ejemplo:

> Los `horarios` 1, 2, 3, 4 y 5 tienen en el campo `Grupo` el código
> `E-1` que pertenece al `Evento` con `id 1`.
>
> Los `horarios` 8, 12, 13, 24 y 26 tienen en el campo `Grupo` el código `A-4` > > que pertenece a la `Asignatura` con `id 4`.
>
> Los `horarios` 6 y 9 tienen en el campo `Grupo` el código `D-3` que pertenece > al `Deber` con `id 3`.

El código del campo `Grupo` lo saco cogiendo la primera letra de la tabla (si son `Eventos` cojo la E, si son `Asignaturas` cojo la A...) más el `id` del registro de la tabla (D-3 = id 3 de la tabla `Deberes`).

Esto es peor aún que meter todas las claves ajenas en la tabla horarios, porque tengo que insertar antes una `Asignatura` con el campo `Grupo` a `null` para poder sacar el código de `Grupo` y luego crear los registros de `horarios` y entonces enlazarlos... Nada, una basura.

Para que os quede claro os dejo un mapa de lo que he implementado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EJEMPLO DE REGISTRO DE HORARIO:
Horario( id = 1, grupo = E-1, fecha = 2016-06-03, hora_inicio = 09:00:00, hora_fin = 10:00:00 )
Horario( id = 2, grupo = E-1, fecha = 2016-06-03, hora_inicio = 10:00:00, hora_fin = 11:00:00 )
Horario( id = 3, grupo = E-1, fecha = 2016-06-04, hora_inicio = 09:00:00, hora_fin = 10:00:00 )

**Lo que estoy preguntando es si la primera forma, la de meter todas las claves ajenas en la tabla horarios, es aceptable o si existe (o veis) otra solución posible. A mi ya no se me ocurre nada y necesito otra visión del problema.**

Las reglas entre las tablas son:

- Los `horarios` relacionados con `Asignaturas`, `Eventos` y `Deberes` tienen que poder verse para no solapar `horarios`.
- Tiene que poder crearse grupos de `horarios`, es decir, el `evento` 1 tiene los `horarios` 1, 2, 3, 4 y 5.

Espero que me puedan echar una mano.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resultó ser, que en SQLite Android no deja que existan claves foráneas nulas, si o si, se tiene que añadir un dato y como el tipo de dato de la clave foránea es `int` no se puede añadir como `null`. Por lo que esta solución no es la más óptima.

Sin embargo, después de estar varios días topandome con problemas e conseguido dar con la solución, ya que era implementar una simple jerarquía que naciera desde la tabla `Horario`, dando como resultado tres tablas que guardaran el id del horario y el id de cada tabla. Justo como se ve en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla `Horario_Evento` iría relacionada con la tabla `Evento`, al igual que la `Horario_Asignatura` con `Asignatura` y `Horario_Deber` con `Deber`.

Answer (score 0):

Poner las claves en la tabla Horario es la solución correcta en mi opinion. Solo tenes que tener en cuenta que esas claves admitan NULL.

Comment: Exacto, de esa forma solucionaría mi problema, aunque tendría que hacer lo que dices y controlar que no se repitiesen en un mismo registro. Lo que me "asusta" es que no sea optimo o este prohibido de alguna forma.